# Elasticsearch return only results that match array of ids

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use elastic search to query only within a set of roomIds?

I tried using bool and should:

```
query: {
    bool: {
        must: [
        {
            multi_match: {
            operator: 'and',
            query: keyword,
            fields: ['content'],
            type: 'most_fields'
            }
        },
        { term: { users: caller } },
        {
            bool: {
            should: 
                term: {
                    room: [list of roomIds]
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
},
```

It works but when I have more than 1k roomIds I get "search_phase_execution_exception".

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For array search you should be using **terms** query instead of **term**

```
query: {
    bool: {
        must: [
        {
            multi_match: {
            operator: 'and',
            query: keyword,
            fields: ['content'],
            type: 'most_fields'
            }
        },
        { term: { users: caller } },
        {
            bool: {
            should: 
                terms: {
                    room: [list of roomIds]
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
},
```

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup)

> By default, Elasticsearch limits the terms query to a maximum of
>   65,536 terms. This includes terms fetched using terms lookup. You can
>   change this limit using the index.max_terms_count setting.